# asp.net 2.0 restore entire viewstate

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm maintaining a legacy ASP.Net 2.0 webforms application, I'll spare the details to avoid complicating the question.  I just want to ask if anyone knows of a way to efficiently restore an entire viewstate.  I can provide more details if necessary, but I'm hoping for something general.  I was hoping I could use the Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium(), but that appears to be a protected method.  Some reading on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) seems to indicate I have to use a custom class that inherits from the PageStatePersister Class and use it's methods to restore an entire state.  Just wanted to get some input from more experienced developers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there are different approaches for this, we used it once in the past for .NET 2 and worked well.

web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
    <pages pageBaseType="PagePersisterBasePage" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

page:

```
public class PagePersisterBasePage : Page
{
    public PagePersisterBasePage()   {
    }
    protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister {
        get {
            return new SessionPageStatePersister(this);
        }
    }
}
```

just as an example, for full article, worth reading it all, go here: [ASP.NET 2.0 Page State Persister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479403.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Davide, this looks promising, I'm testing out some implementations now.  Will post updates.

Answer (score 0):

Good article here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7655/Persisting-the-state-of-a-web-page

This restores the ViewState,  resets all controls and talks about restoring request.form()

Comment: there is a problem with checkboxes that has the autopostback attribute set to true.
If the user handles that checked event and relies on other stuff on the page ( that hasn't been loaded yet) it may be too early for the checkbox, thus resulting in invalid references... 
 
So some workaround has to be made so that the checkbox's check event is not fired in LoadPost data.

CAN YOU HELP ME ?